# ubuntu 20.04 desktop black screen after logging in

Tags: gnome, 20.04, xorg, screen

I installed ubuntu 20.04 desktop on my PC, of which the hardware configurations are listed as follow:

```
CPU: i9 10900k
RAM: KLEVV 32GB (16GBx2)
Disk: WD sn750 1TB
GPU: i9 10900k build-in GPU
```

after logging in, the screen went black immediately, where there is only a mouse cursor. But I could still log in using ssh. And when I ran `top` in the ssh terminal, I got the following message:

```
top - 18:34:57 up 1 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.84, 0.25, 0.09
Tasks: 438 total,   2 running, 435 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.8 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  31962.9 total,  30269.2 free,    873.7 used,    820.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2048.0 free,      0.0 used.  30571.4 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   1818 iterator  20   0  809424  60388  37524 R  93.0   0.2   0:22.31 Xorg
   1966 iterator  20   0 3744356 185436  86840 S  10.0   0.6   0:02.99 gnome-shell
   2016 iterator  20   0  162828   7468   6688 S   3.3   0.0   0:00.73 at-spi2-registr
   1910 iterator  20   0  127220  39636  21100 S   3.0   0.1   0:00.67 fcitx
   2001 iterator  20   0  193656  19184  17044 S   2.3   0.1   0:00.46 ibus-x11
   1999 iterator  20   0  277372  30336  19824 S   2.0   0.1   0:00.91 ibus-extension-
    888 root      20   0 2773024  29444  15024 S   0.3   0.1   0:00.80 snapd
    947 root      20   0 1116944  45692  25224 S   0.3   0.1   0:00.31 containerd
      1 root      20   0  167924  11636   8292 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.79 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
```

where there is a process named `Xorg` taking over about a whole CPU core. And the detailed command of that process after running `ps -aux | grep 1818` is `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3`. I have tried many solutions after an exhaustive searching online, yet no solution works for me.

Comment: Silly question, but what kind of mouse are you using? I've seen instances where certain "gaming mice" can overload Xorg by sending data at 1000MHz, which is quite a bit higher than the typical 150MHz that most pointing devices use.

Comment: silly....?? I am using Logitech Master 2S, could it be the problem of this ?

Comment: It *could* be, but it's not too difficult to test. First check your polling rate with `systool -m usbhid -A mousepoll`. You should see something like `Module = "usbhid" mousepoll = "0"` (spread out on two lines). The `"0"` means "read at full speed" (which usually isn't a lot for a mouse). From there, create a file named `/etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf` as `root` and add this line: `options usbhid mousepoll=8` (or any number between 0 and 10, really). The higher the number, the less often the device will be polled. Then `modprobe -r usbhid && modprobe usbhid` to set the polling rate.